# A list of all possible Excel GUID

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to implement something in the office that runs from powerpoint and goes into excel, but to do so I need to add a reference to Excel (unless I do late binding, which I don't want to do.) This is the code that will be adding the GUID reference:

```
'Activate Excel Library (version 2.0)
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
      GUID:="{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
      Major:=0, Minor:=0
```

The issue here is that not everyone in the office has the same version of Excel. I need to be able to add a reference to anyone's Excel. Is there a list out there somewhere of all possible GUIDs since like office 2003?
Or maybe there's a different way I'm not thinking of to do this?

Comment: I don't think late binding will give you _that much_ of a decrease in performance. If your code is small, you won't even notice it.

Comment: Late binding is going to work best for you, as when a new version of Excel comes out, you wont have to change your code. It will just work. Why do you not want to use late binding?

Comment: @braX my code is quite large, and currently takes between 2-6 minutes to complete depending on the size of the file I'm working with. I've done as much optimizing as I can to reduce it to this size. Late binding was an option I explored a while back but it slowed the program down significantly...

Comment: The only reason I can think of for it to slow you down that much is if you had your `CreateObject` call inside of a loop, which would not be the right way to structure the code in the first place.

Comment: I couldn't find a complete list. You might just have to try different versions to get them all. It does leave you in the position that you will have to maintain the list though. If you're really against late binding, and don't want to maintain the list, you could obtain the CLSID dynamically using `clsid = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCR\Excel.Application\CLSID\")`.

Comment: FYI - the CLSID for Excel 2016 is `{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`. Maybe if everyone puts theirs you'll end up with your list :).

Comment: [Christoph Damoser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15373669) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66577873) saying "Maybe this post help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0daa06d-c6ac-4582-afc9-92df27ab98d3/how-to-get-programmatically-a-list-of-all-available-references-of-a-vba-project?forum=isvvba&amp;prof=required There is a macro from Peter Thornton which list all references GUID, path and name (->; .Reference.Description)"